# Pass props between three components

Tags: reactjs

I need to show data depending on an active device (which can be iphone or ipad). I have 3 components: App, DeviceCheck and Collection. Device check is a component with 2 buttons, Iphone and iPad. In a Collection component I'm parsing data from an external file, for example something like:

```
const applications = [
  {
    device: 'iPhone',
    icon: icon,
    title: 'title',
    descr: 'descr',
    category: 'Games',
    link: 'link-to-appstore',
    price: 0.99,
    purchases: true
  },
  {
    device: 'iPad',
    icon: icon2,
    title: 'title2',
    descr: 'descr2',
    category: 'Games',
    link: 'link',
    price: 1.99,
    purchases: false,
  }
]
```

The App.js structure is:

```
<DeviceCheck />
<Collection />
```

How do I show the iPhone or iPad data in Collection component, depending on which button was clicked in DeviceCheck component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a component which passes a callback to the device check.
2. Use this callback to update the state of the container from the device check.
3. Use the state in the container to set the props of the collection.

This is very common in React and is the basis of how the compositional pattern works. If you need to share data between two components just put them in a container and lift the state to the parent component. These components are usually called containers and there is a bunch of documentation on it.

This is a good starting point: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

A rough layout would be something like this.

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Don't forget to bind the handler to the correct context
    this.changeDevice = this.changeDevice.bind(this);
  }

  changeDevice(device) {
    this.setState({device: device});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DeviceCheck btnCb={this.changeDevice} />
      <Collection device={this.state.device} />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Maintain a variable in the state of `App.js` called `selectedDevice`.
2. In the click handler of the buttons call `setState()` to modify `selectedDevice` in state.
3. Use `selectedDevice` to show the corresponding data in `<Collection />`

Answer (score 1):

It's a little broad your question, but you can hold a `state` object with the selected device and use `setState` on `<DeviceCheck />` button click to set the selected one. and `<Collection {...selectedDevice} />` will use the state object as input.

Answer (score 1):

In the App component you can have deviceType as the state and a function which sets the deviceType based on the parameter and this function should be passed as props to the DeviceCheck component. Upon clicking button the in the DeviceCheck button, you need to invoke the prop function with corresponding button type as parameter. The deviceType state should be passed onto the Collection component as prop and based on the prop value, the Collection component can render the respective Device data. Hope this helps!