# Display some text in react depending on the switch case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown populated from  a Web Service, what I want is to display some text according to the selection made. For example the first option in the Dropdown is **Buy n and Save m** so in a p tag I want to display **Buy 2 and Save $1.5** I know this is work for a switch and the position of the array is going to be my "CASE" in order to know what to display or not but I'm new to react and also in programming so I need help..

```
import React from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem'; 
import cr from '../styles/general.css';

export default class Example extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      OfferTypeData: [],
      OfferTypeState: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.renderOfferTypeOptions = this.renderOfferTypeOptions.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const offerTypeWS = 'http://localhost:8080/services/OfferType/getAll';

    fetch(offerTypeWS)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);

        this.setState({
          OfferTypeData: findResponse
        });
      });
  }

  handleChange(event, index, value) {this.setState({value});}

  handleChangeDiscountType(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({ OfferTypeState: (value) });
  }

  renderOfferTypeOptions() {
    return this.state.OfferTypeData.map((dt, i) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={i}
          value={dt.offerTypeDesc}
          primaryText={dt.offerTypeDesc} />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className={cr.container}>
        <div className={cr.rows}>
          <div>
            <DropDownMenu
              value={this.state.OfferTypeState}
              onChange={this.handleChangeDiscountType}>
              <MenuItem value={''} primaryText={'Select Offer Type'} />
              {this.renderOfferTypeOptions()}
            </DropDownMenu>
            <br/>
            <p>{DISPLAY SOME TEXT HERE}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but I don't think a switch statement is required.  Are you just looking to display the value selected in the dropdown inside the `<p>`?

Comment: What is a "WS"?  What exactly isn't working here?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, WS = Web services, I just edit my question to be more clear. and no, I don't want to display the value of the dropdown in a p tag, what I want is to display different data depending on the selection made on the dropdown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass props between three components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577900/pass-props-between-three-components)

Answer (score 0):

Create a component which passes a callback to the dropdown, this callback will update the state of the container which will in turn set the props of the display. This is very common in React and is the basis of how the compositional pattern works. If you need to share data between two components just put them in a container and lift the state to the parent component. These components are usually called containers and there is a bunch of documentation on it.

This is a good starting point: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

A rough layout would be something like this.

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Don't forget to bind the handler to the correct context
    this.changeText = this.changeText.bind(this);
  }

  changeText(text) {
    this.setState({text: text});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DropDown callback={this.changeText} />
      <Display text={this.state.text} />
    )
  }
}
```

Display component...

```
const Display = (props) => (
  <p>{this.props.text}</p>
)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time....  but where should I tell react to display text inside the p tag according to the dropdown selection?

Comment: For example if I select the the first option of my dropdown I'll get a 0 because it's the first position so i I get a 0 then I print "position 0" for give a example....

Comment: You can't conditionally render like that you need to have a container that updates the props of a display component that renders a p tag when the dropdown changes. I added a display component to my answer.

Comment: If you are certain all you need to do is render that text then you can probably add a field to your state to do it instead of making a component. I think it's much easier to split this problem up into 3 components though.